# Binding collection from XML in Windows Store async

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous, windows-store-apps

In my app.xaml.cs I am creating XML using this code:

```
private async static void CreateXML()
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Data", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile st = await sf.CreateFileAsync("Badgess.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        XmlDocument dom = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement x;

        x = dom.CreateElement("badges");
        dom.AppendChild(x);

        XmlElement x1 = dom.CreateElement("badge");

        XmlElement x11 = dom.CreateElement("id");
        x11.InnerText = "1";
        x1.AppendChild(x11);

        XmlElement x12 = dom.CreateElement("name");
        x12.InnerText = "Badge One";
        x1.AppendChild(x12);

        XmlElement x13 = dom.CreateElement("pictureurl");
        x13.InnerText = "two.png";
        x1.AppendChild(x13);

        XmlElement x14 = dom.CreateElement("isachieved");
        x14.InnerText = "false";
        x1.AppendChild(x14);

        x.AppendChild(x1);

        await dom.SaveToFileAsync(st);
    }
```

When the app is started I can't see this data, I am using repository pattern and bind object to observableList like this:

```
public async Task<IList<Badge>> GetAll()
    {
        StorageFolder sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync("Data");
        StorageFile st = await sf.GetFileAsync("Badgess.xml");

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(st));

        var data = from query in doc.Descendants("badge")
                   select new Badge
                  {
                      Id = (int)query.Element("id"),
                      Name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                      PictureURL = (string)query.Element("pictureurl"),
                      IsAchieved = (bool)query.Element("isachieved"),
                  };

        return (IList<Badge>)data.ToList();
    }
```

Binding:

```
IList<Badge> list = await _badgeService.GetAll();

        BadgesList = list.ToObservableCollection<Badge>();
```

It appears only when I go to the another view of the app and then go back to the main view, it is not appear after application is starting and I do not know why?
Will be great if some could help me because I am fighting with this for 2 days and have no idea, the project is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame), so you can take a look if you need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not raising `INotifyPropertyChanged` when you set `BadgesList` in `GetBadges`. Remember that `async` will "pause" your method and *return* - so `BadgesList` is *not* being set in your constructor.

However, I recommend more of a redesign. You should strongly avoid `async void`. I have some blog posts on [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) and [`async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) (supporting data binding) that are a much better fit for ViewModels than `async void`.

Comment: Ok, you are right I think I was blind, this code is working but now I am lost blendability? how to get this two working together?

Comment: I know very little about Blend. I recommend you create a minimal repro and post another question.

Comment: it is possible to use your suggestions from blog post using MVVM Light in my ViewModels?

Comment: I am going to read about it on your blog, I almost got what I want, but need to know more, thx